# Regular Language to DFA conversion

Tags: regular-language, dfa

I ran into a problem in a textbook that I can't decipher and I was hoping you could help. I'm not asking for a solution, just a translation, or a push in the right direction. This is in the JFLAP textbook.

> The alphabet consists only of "a".
>
> ```
> {a^L |L = 0 (mod 6), L /= 0 (mod 4) }
> ```
>
> Construct a DFA that recognizes this language.

I assume that if the string of a's is a multiple of 6 the string will be accepted, but I don't really understand what L/= 0 would mean. There are multiple questions like this.

Again, I don't need, or want, an answer to the problem, but maybe a translation to an english sentence would help me to understand what they are asking for.

Comment: It simply means that `L` must satisfy two conditions: be divisble by 6 and not divisible by 4. E.g. 6 is ok, but 24 is not.

Comment: I assume it means 'not equal to', but the book probably gives the notation somewhere near the beginning? So the length of strings in L are multiples of 6 but not of 4..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`L /= 0 (mod 4)` means that L is not congruent to 0 mod 4 (the opposite of `L = 0 (mod 4)`)

When you write it by hand, you actually put a slash through the symbol (like ≠)